# Separating the interface from an implementation in Java

Tags: java

How can you separate the interface from an implementation in Java?

In C/C++, this can be done by creating 2 files a .c and .h file with the same file name.
How can you do this in Java?

Comment: You may be looking for Java interfaces. They are not exactly the same though.

Comment: Do I need to create two .java files with the same file name? one has the interface and the other has the implementation definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest analogy to .h and .c separation is interfaces.

**MyInterface.java**

```
interface MyInterface {

    void doSomething();

}
```

**MyImplementation.java**

```
class MyImplementation implements MyInterface {

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }

}
```

You then use the interface type everywhere except for the actual constructor

```
MyInterface instance = new MyImplementation();
```

Of course, there are several differences.

- A single class may implement multiple interfaces, and multiple classes may a single interface
- Member values are not included in an interface, only methods.
- Only public methods appears in a Java interface.
- No implementation is ever allowed in an interface (as opposed to C++ templates, which depend on .h implementation).

But this is how "programming to interfaces" is accomplished.

---

There is no consistent convention for naming interfaces vs concrete classes in Java. C# (nearly identical in its treatment of interfaces) has a convention which I have come to use where the interface begins with `I`, e.g. `IList`. The Java standard libraries tend to use the "pure" name for the interface, and then modify it for the concrete implementation, such as `List` (interface) and `ArrayList` (implementation).

Answer (score 2):

By creating an `interface`, and implementing it also (generally) in two files -

`Say.java` the interface -

```
public interface Say {
  public void say(String msg);
}
```

and `Hello.java`, the concrete implementation (and in this case) also a `main()` method -

```
public class Hello implements Say {
  @Override
  public void say(String msg) {
    System.out.printf("%s, World!%n", msg);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Say s = new Hello();
    s.say("Hello");
  }
}
```

**Note**: In Java you can have multiple classes with `main()` methods. It is also a good practice to use the `@Override` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  You could do it via Java interfaces, but doing that for every class would be bad design.  Interfaces should only be used when you expect multiple classes to implement them, or when used as a callback function description.  Really the point of separating the code from the .h file in C++ is

1)To prevent bloating the binary as compilers would make multiple versions of each function for each file its included in

2)To make it easier to read for those who just want the implementation.

In java, 1 isn't an issue.  And Java prefers to solve 2 via automated documentation tools (JavaDoc).

TLDR-  you don't.

Comment: "Interfaces should only be used when you expect multiple classes to implement them" Just to clarify: in many Java libraries there are interfaces that only have one implementation. However, these will be cases in which it would be reasonable to have a different implementation. "You don't" is probably too strong.

Comment: I'll stick by you don't.  Until you actually write that 2nd implementation, its wasted effort.  And when you actually start it, you almost always end up changing the interface for the better.  I wouldn't break off an interface until there's at least 2 implementations.  The exception being callback interfaces, where the definition is needed by the class making the callback.

Comment: so, is it normal for some classes in a java program to not have an interface?

Comment: The vast majority of them do not.  Interfaces are meant for callbacks and for behavior with multiple implementations.  For example, List, which has ArrayList and LinkedList for different implementations.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, interfaces and classes (ie "implementation") are **NOT** distinguished at file level or by their names. They are both declarations. Specifically, a class declares which interface(s) it implements. For example:

```
public class MyClass implements Interface1, Interface2, .... {
    // implementations
}
```

Java does not have the same "linking" concept as in C/C++. You can call your class or interface in any legal form. The "link" between an interface and its implementation classes at runtime are done through the class loader.

Answer (score 0):

To have an interface and implementation separated, suggest below steps..

( 1).Identify methods which be part of definition of your class. This becomes your template for new classes with similar functionality.

(2 ). Create a new interface which contains methods which were identified to be part of interface definition (may be many interfaces)

( 3.) Modify your class to implement the interface(s) you have created